# What is the difference between private method and final method in java?

Tags: java

What I am asking "In Functionality point of view 'private`and`final` methods are not overriden". 
Can we use Only one Access Modifier i.e Private in functionality point of view?

Comment: private methods are inherently final. final specifier can be used to stop a non-private method to get overridden.

Answer (score 11):

`private` is about accessibility like `public` or `protected` or no modifier.
`final` is about modification during inheritance.

- `private` methods are not just accessible from the outside of the class.
- `final` methods can not be overridden by the child class.

As `private` method is not accessible from the child classes it also **cannot be overridden** but `final` method can or can not be accessible based on the access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Private method cannot accessible out side of the class mean suppose A is class having sum() is private method. And we want to call method sum() from class B by creating the object of A class..it is not possible so at last private method cannot accessible out side of the class for the security where as final method cant be overridden.